# Foundation 6: get a horizontal line after each row

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using Foundation's `grid-x` which is powered by CSS flexbox.

Is there a small, simple and straightforward way to have rows and columns of responsive tiles (where the count of tiles per row is unknown)  have a visual separator (e.g., a good old fashioned `<hr>` element) between each row? I'm using Foundation's `class="row" and class="column"` to render the responsive tiles.

What I'm trying to achieve is basically this: [Add a horizontal line separator on rows of wrapping items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650273/add-a-horizontal-line-separator-on-rows-of-wrapping-items)      but with minimal hacking of Foundation's Css or markup.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest solution I can think of is to have a css class that has solid bottom border:

```
.solid-border-bottom{border-bottom: 0.25rem solid gray;}
```

On the above code you could change the thickness and color; based on your needs

Then in any `div` you want to have the `<hr>` effect you use this class, something like:

```
<div class"columns solid-border-bottom">
```